# Where is @AroundInvoke interceptor invoked?

Tags: jakarta-ee, interceptor

I'm doing some test examples with java, and I come up with an example that uses @AroundInvoke. The question is that I don't know exactly where is the method invoked.

This test makes an invocation where it calls post() method, but I don't really know how that works ([Using Interceptors explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html)).

```
@Test
public void crudtest() {
    JsonObjectBuilder todoBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonObject todoToCreate = todoBuilder.
            add("caption", "implement").
            add("priority", 10).
            build();

    //The next post execute, invoke the method
    Response postResponse = this.provider.target().request().
            post(Entity.json(todoToCreate));
}
```

The order of invocation is BoundaryLogger and then MonitorSink

**BoundaryLogger.java**

```
...
public class BoundaryLogger {

    @Inject
    Event<CallEvent> monitoring;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logCall(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            return ic.proceed();
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            monitoring.fire(new CallEvent(ic.getMethod().getName(), duration));
        }
    }
}
```

**MonitorSink**

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MonitorSink {

    @Inject
    LogSink LOG;

    public void onCallEvent(@Observes CallEvent event){
        LOG.log(event.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out, by doing an other interceptor example.

@AroundInvoke just define an interceptor that it will be invoked by the class that has @Interceptor(name_class.class).

In my case, this was the code I was missing to look at it.

**ToDoManager.java**

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(BoundaryLogger.class)
public class ToDoManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public ToDo findById(long id) {
        return this.em.find(ToDo.class,id);
    }

    public void delete(long id) {
        try {
            ToDo reference = this.em.getReference(ToDo.class, id);
            this.em.remove(reference);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
            //we want to remove it...
        }
    }

    public List<ToDo> all() {
        return this.em.createNamedQuery(ToDo.findAll, ToDo.class).getResultList();
    }

    public ToDo save(ToDo todo) {
        return this.em.merge(todo);
    }

    public ToDo updateStatus(long id, boolean done) {
        ToDo todo = this.findById(id);
        if(todo == null){
            return null;
        }
        todo.setDone(done);
        return todo;
    }

}
```

The @AroundInvoke annotation is used to designate interceptor methods for managed object methods.

I hope, that this could help someone else!